# Why does this Label look different when bound than it does with a static value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a label in a border.  If I use a static value for the content of the label with this markup:

```
  <Border Background="#FFEEEEEE"
          Grid.Column="4"
          Grid.Row="3"
          Margin="2 0">
    <Label Content="0"
           Name="ui_quantityFooter"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="20" />
  </Border>
```

it looks like this:

[image: Correctly aligned label]

However, if I bind to an integer value in the ViewModel with this markup:

```
  <Border Background="#FFEEEEEE"
          Grid.Column="4"
          Grid.Row="3"
          Margin="2 0">
    <Label Content="{Binding ExpectedQuantity}"
           Name="ui_quantityFooter"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="20" />
  </Border>
```

It looks like this:
[image: Badly aligned label]

Why don't they have the same appearance?

**Edit**:  ExpectedQuantity is defined as:

```
public int ExpectedQuantity {
  get { return _expectedQuantity; }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what type is ExpectedQuantity - just 'Int'? Is this reproducable in a simple case? (I've just tried it locally and I don't see the same issue)

Comment: Yeah, it is an int.  I'm going to try using a string, perhaps there is some interference with my styles on that data type.

Comment: Those windows are different widths.  If they are the same what happens.  HorizontalAlignement is for the control.  For the content use HorizontalContentAlignment.  I suspect you are getting a different default on HorizontalContentAlignment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The images above are cropped screenshots of a larger UI -- I suppose it was sloppy of me to crop them differently.  Interestingly, when I use string as my data type rather than int, it aligns correctly.  I'll have to investigate the cause for this.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking (difference in data-type), but I can't repro it, so it has to be some other part of your XAML. You could also try running Snoop - it might tell you where the difference in style is coming from.

Comment: Have you tried flipping your Label for a TextBlock instead? Label derives from ContentControl (which could be causing your issue) whereas TextBlock derives directly from FrameworkElement.

Comment: I did try with a TextBlock and had the same effect.

Comment: Why does everything sound like a Win8 / VS2012 bug to me? Am I the only one who feels it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the data type to string causes the issue to go away, so a style must be affecting the content of the label when its data type is int.